# Moving to the next iteration after a condition is met

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey so I currently have a discord command where it allows you find out if a user sent 30+ messages in a list of channels. Right now the problem is that the top loop (for user in userList) doesn't cycle through to the next user even though I have `return` at the bottom. Is there another way of cycling through users once the bottom message condition has met?

```py
for user in userList:
    counter = 0
    for channel in channelList:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=None, after=yesterday):
            if message.author == user:
                counter += 1
                if counter == messageQuery:
                    listUserCompleted.append(message.author.display_name)
                    return
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation? - the second to last line can't be in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to break out of just the inner `for` loop and move on to the next `user`, then you want to use a `break` statement, like this:

```
for user in userList:
    counter = 0
    for channel in channelList:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=None, after=yesterday):
            if message.author == user:
                counter += 1
                if counter == messageQuery:
                    listUserCompleted.append(message.author.display_name)
                    break
```

That will break out of the innermost loop that you're in, which is the `for channel...`.

Answer (score -1):

Return returns the entire function and stops the Function block from executing.

Use the keyword `continue` instead to get to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I think you mean `break`.  `continue` is a no-op in this case, since you're already at the bottom of the loop and will just cycle back up to the top of the inner loop either way.

Comment: Ah ei missundersood his question sorry